# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, xampp

I am trying to login to mysql using the user pass that I have in the XAMPP conf files however I get the following error:

```
mysql -u mysql -p;                                                                                                                            1 ✘  at 11:48:02 AM 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have entered `1234` as password which is in the conf file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf` below:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
password        =1234
port            =3306
socket          =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
user=mysql
port=3306
socket          =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=1M
table_open_cache=64
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
```

Also, here's info from running mysql daemons:

```
ps aux | grep mysql                                                                                                                      PIPE|2 ✘  at 11:55:38 AM 
mona              6189   0.0  0.0  4286736    724 s003  S+   11:56AM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql
_mysql            5707   0.0  0.0  4589008   8172   ??  S    11:53AM   0:00.10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/plugin/ --log-error=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/goku.err --pid-file=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/goku.pid --socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
root              5555   0.0  0.0  4308708    844   ??  S    11:53AM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --pid-file=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/goku.pid
```

Here's what I see in XAMPP:

[image]

I have OSX Catalina 10.15.7 (19H1713).

After uncommenting the password and setting it to `1234` I stopped and started the mySQL in XAMPP UI but still not able to login.

I entered like the following, but still, it doesn't go to mysql shell:
`mysql -u mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -port 3306 -p 1234;`

and I see something like:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 8.0.29 for macos12 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
```

Without passing the port information (since 3306 is the default port), I get this error, this is despite `1234` is the password I set in mysql conf file from xampp):

```
mysql -u mysql  -h 127.0.0.1 -p;                                                                                                              1 ✘  at 12:29:02 PM 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysql'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql -u root  -h 127.0.0.1 -p;                                                                                                               1 ✘  at 12:34:13 PM 
Enter password:
```

When it asks for password, press enter and you are now in mysql shell. You can see a list of existing users here:

```
mysql> SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
+------+
| user |
+------+
| root |
| root |
|      |
| pma  |
| root |
+------+
```

Now, create a user and set a password for it such as:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'mona'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
+------+
| user |
+------+
| root |
| root |
|      |
| mona |
| pma  |
| root |
+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now quit the mysql shell and enter the following command in front of the prompt:

`mysql -u mona  -h 127.0.0.1 -p;`
and for password enter `1234`.

You now enter the mysql shell for user `mona`.

For more info check [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql).